# use default value in partition clause of a window function if null

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, isnull

I have used window functions in my query to sum my rows according to value in combination of rows. Now If 1 row contains null then I have to consider it as false what should i do? I had tried adding `coalesce(atg.flag,false)` in partition but it didn't work.

Comment: `coalesce(atg.flag,false)` should work. referencing partitions - are you speaking about window functions?..

Comment: Yes I am using windows function.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the query you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

coalesce is the way, here is an example:

```
t=# with dset(i,bool) as (values(1,true),(2,false),(3,null))
select i, bool::text, count(1) over (partition by coalesce(bool,false))
from dset;
 i | bool  | count
---+-------+-------
 2 | false |     2
 3 |       |     2
 1 | true  |     1
(3 rows)
```

as you can see count =2 for null and false and =1 for true